# How to access a Div inside a repeater using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

Simply, I have an anchor inside a repeater that triggers on click a javascript function, which sets the innerHTML of a Div to some content.

trying this outside a repeater did work!
but if I tried to implement the same code in the repeater's item template, it won't work!

**NOTE:** I think I need to access the repeater first then access the Anchor inside it! but I don't know how to do it

For further illustration:

JavaScript Function:

```
function show(ele, content) {
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(ele);
    if (srcElement != null) {
        srcElement.innerHTML = content;
    }
}
```

The repeater's code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        Name : <%# Eval("name")%>
        <DIV ID= "PersonalInfo1" runat="server"></DIV>
        <A id="A1" href="#" runat="server" onclick="show('PersonalInfo1','Address : ')">More...</A>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**PS: THE POSTED CODE ISN'T WORKING IN THE REPEATER!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... let's start over.

Have such repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            Name : <%# Eval("name")%>
            <div id="Address" runat="server" style="display: none;"><%# Eval("address")%></div>
            <div id="Interests" runat="server" style="display: none;"><%# Eval("interests")%></div>
            <a id="A1" href="#" runat="server" onclick="return show(this, 'Address');">Show address</a>
            <a id="A2" href="#" runat="server" onclick="return show(this, 'Interests');">Show interests</a>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then such JavaScript code:

```
function show(oLink, targetDivID) {
    var arrDIVs = oLink.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrDIVs.length; i++) {
        var oCurDiv = arrDIVs[i];
        if (oCurDiv.id.indexOf(targetDivID) >= 0) {
            var blnHidden = (oCurDiv.style.display == "none");
            oCurDiv.style.display = (blnHidden) ? "block" : "none";
            //oLink.innerHTML = (blnHidden) ? "Less..." : "More...";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will search for "brother" DIV element of the clicked link, and show or hide it.

The code is as simple as possible using pure JavaScript, you should be able to understand what each line is doing - feel free to ask if you don't. :)

Note, you have to put the personal info in the PersonalInfo div in advance instead of passing it to the function - the function will get pointer to the clicked link.

Comment: You can see live example (static HTML) here: http://jsfiddle.net/TEFnh/ and you can also mess around with the JS code in there. :)

Comment: I can't deny that this is exactly what I wanted to implement!
but to be honest I don't quite get it!
First, you sent the Anchor object to the function, then you used a "parentNode" property! what is this exactly ?
I could have simply searched for any anchor using the getByTagName function! right ?

Comment: A BUG i just discovered!! when I click more it shows the information in all the DIVs and when I click less, it hides all the divs!
but of course I hope I could hide/show the div of only the given item!

Comment: @lKashef - to fix the BUG, simply wrap each item (in the repeater) with DIV element, I've edited my code accordingly. parentNode of the clicked link will then return the new wrapper DIV element, and then you will iterate over its child DIV elements searching for the one with proper ID.

Comment: Look Shadow, I'm getting to understand this snippet but I still have some answers if you could help with. What is the parentNode exactly mean or do ? and also what's the meaning and the function of "indexOf" and what's the comparison you used means (>= 0)!!

Comment: I want to add another div and edit the first div (PersonalInfo1), so I could have Address Div and ID Div...and two Anchors, when the address anchor is clicked it shows the address div and so on! I've tried but I'm trapped again!! :S

Comment: @lKashef - parentNode means the parent node of the element. Suppose you have this HTML: `<div id="div1"><div id="div2">hello</div></div>` so the parent node of div2 is div1. indexOf returns the first index of the given string, for example `"hello".indexOf("l")` will return 2 because the first index of "l" is 2 - remember that count starts from 0. I'm using this to search for the string "PersonalInfo" inside the ID of the current element in the loop. As for your new request it's not complicated, I'll add that to my post later today when I have some time and update you here.

Comment: @lKashef - please see the edited code it now support more than one div, in the example I'm showing address and interests. Let me know if you need further explanations or something is still not right..

Comment: @Shadow- GREAT THANKS! working very smoothly (Y)..I have some questions, I hope you could help with them any time you are free! 1- using indexOf(x) does it have to be a comparison..I mean I'm sure about what I'm targetting (the Address div for example) can't I just say == TargetDiv 2- what's the use of this line "return false;" ?
I REALLY APPRECIATE YOUR HELP, thanks for your time =D

Comment: @lKashef - 1) Being inside control, the true ID will be something like MyControl1_Address so it must be covered otherwise we'll never find the control. 2) The default behavior of link is to redirect user to different page. Without returning false, the page will be reloaded and we want to avoid that. The `return false;` tells the browser: don't continue with your default behavior. 3) No problem. :)

Comment: @Shadow - you was really a great help, I think I've got the whole picture.
Thanks to you =)

Answer (score 3):

That is because id's are unique. Select elements using getElementsByName or by their class name with for example jQuery.

Comment: well, I want to access a specific anchor..so I specified it's ID!
isn't that better and direct ?

Comment: @lKashef: You cannot use an ID multiple times. It has to be unique across the whole document. What exactly do you mean by anchor? If you have multiple ones, which one should it jump to?

Comment: @lKashef - if you don't want to delve into jQuery ATM use my code and add simple if checking the id of `oLink` in the loop.

Comment: forget about my implementation! =)
I have a repeater that will show the name of all the items (people) in a specific db table...now, without having to refresh my page (using ajax, jquery, or similar technologies i dunno) I need to place an anchor or text button whatever that says "More.." and when it's clicked it has to show some extra data (from the db) like the address...I hope I'm clear about my goal! thanks elusive =D

Comment: @lKashef - that's cool, your initial idea should work just fine.

Comment: I'm asking a lot of questions, I just want to understand not just get my code to run!
my question is! how to get it to work! :S i mean why should I loop through all the anchors when I have one specific anchor -problem is ,it's inside a repeater!-

Comment: @lKashef the problem is that when you have repeater, you have several links and several DIV elements and you don't know their ID in advance so you need to find them at runtime.

Comment: so giving the DIV a unique id (PersonalInfo1) doesn't mean that it will be unique at runtime..because it will be created with every item in the repeater!..i think that was something essential i had to understand...I got it right or what ?

Comment: @lKashef - well done, you're correct.. ASP.NET generates unique ID values, based on the ID you give but not identical to it. See my new answer, it should finally contain the code you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to iterate all the relevant links. Solution that involve minimal change of code is adding class to the links then check for this class:

```
<A id="A1" href="#" runat="server" class="RepeaterLink" ...>
```

And then in JavaScript:

```
var arrLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < arrLinks.length; i++) {
    var oLink = arrLinks[i];
    if (oLink.className == "RepeaterLink") {
        //found link inside repeater..
        oLink.click();
    }
}
```

This will "auto click" all the links, you can check ID or something else to imitate click of specific link in the repeater as well.

Comment: By the way, using jQuery the JavaScript code can be shortened and be more "browser safe". It's your call. :)

Comment: Actually, I was researching about the difference between (Javascript, JQuery, Ajax) I know the definition for each of them but I don't know what are they exactly used for ?
of course i'd consider using JQuery if you think it's better, but any guides or pointers would help (Y) !

Comment: @lKashef - jQuery is library of JavaScript - all you need to do is add reference to jQuery code file and you can use it. Think of cakes: you can bake the cake yourself (pure JavaScript) or you can buy the cake, made by someone else, in the store. (jQuery)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: You need to mention, that this cake from the store was made by pretty skilled people, so you can be quite sure that it will taste the same across various browsers.

Comment: @elusive - good point.. and the price of the cake is ~80 kilobytes. :D

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: but you still have to decorate the cake yourself :)

Comment: Thank you both, the picture is way more clear about javascript and JQuery...but what about AJAX ? when to use it ? is it a substitute for Jquery or it has its own implementation ?

Comment: @lKashef: AJAX is not a language or something like that. It is a technique used to recieve XML/HTML content in the background without reloading the entrie page. Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming\).

Comment: @lKashef - AJAX is completely different animal. Its purpose is sending stuff to server side language from the client side, and JavaScript must be used somehow.. jQuery is wrapping it very nicely. Can't see how it's relevant in your case, at least not from what you told us so far.

Comment: Yh I know that it uses Javascripts and some other existing technologies! but how can you use it ? the example here itself is retrieving the address without reloading the entire page!...you see what I mean ? so what's the difference ? can AJAX be used in this example ?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - "Its purpose is sending stuff" ? or sending and receiving ??

Comment: @lKashef - in your case AJAX is not required as you already have all the data in the page so there's no point to request for that data. AJAX is used to send stuff, and you can receive and analyze the output sent by the server. If you need help finding specific link using my code let me know. :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, i was trying to make things smiple! I'll be fetching the address info from a database, It won't be static 'Address:...', it will be dynamic using 'Eval("address")....now i'm receiving from the server right ?